# How to integrate Sitemap.xml and Robot.txt files generated from free online source to Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, seo, sitemap

"I have **Sitemap.xml** and **Robot.txt** files generated from free online sources, and I want to integrate those with my Spring Boot Application" and want to access that as **http://localhost:8080/Sitemap.xml**.

Previously I work with Struts 2.x. where I usually drop those files in JSPs folder and I able to access that as **http://localhost:8080/Sitemap.xml**.

But here in Spring Boot Application, I am totally confused in adding them to Application. (My Doubts are listed Below).

1. In which folder I need to add these files?

2.Does it need any controller to access Sitemap.xml as **http://localhost:8080/Sitemap.xml**.

Help me in Sorting out this.

Thanks in Advance.

Added **Sitemap.xml** and **Robot.txt** under static folder, but no use of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can add these files under public folder in src/main/resources.
For more info refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Also, if you have security configuration then you need to modify as below:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/Sitemap.xml");
    }
```